# Issues in version uploaded on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I uploaded my app to GAE for java which is mapped to our domain www.sakshum.org

The default version is  http://3.sakshumweb.appspot.com/

The problem is when we access using the domain name it seems to have some old version but if we access the direct url it seems to be working fine.

Any idea on what could be the issue?

Comment: Is this a permanent problem? Static files on GAE get cached for about 10 minutes.

Comment: problem is with the application code written in GWT. and moreover accessing the app using http://3.sakshumweb.appspot.com/ works fine but using http://www.sakshum.org fails. in last 3 years we are facing this issue for the first time

Comment: Pending my reply? You clearly dont understand how things work here. Nobody owes you anything. You should do your own debugging..

Comment: Do you see GWT problem on one browser or across browsers? How about different computers?

Comment: yes i tried in different browsers as well as on different computers and my problem is reproducible

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you set version 3 as the default version on the application dashboard (Main, Versions)? It could be that, for some weird reason, the instances serving the previous version are still alive. You may want to shut them down and see what happens.

Comment: yes to keep the things simple we have just one version deployed on our app engine under versions which is version 3. To avoid other possibilities i tried to shutdown all the instances and then opened the site freshly in incognito mode and I still see the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files on GAE get cached for about 10 minutes. You should try disabling cache for GWT related files. Put this into your `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
<static-files>
  <include path="**" />

  <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
  <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

  <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
  <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
</static-files>
```

Comment: yes we have these included but i still see the old version of the app even after half an hour. just to repeat http://3.sakshumweb.appspot.com seems to be fine but http://www.sakshum.org seems to have old code. not sure why this is happening

Comment: 1. Check that you surely have the correct version as default version.

Comment: 2. Download code from GAE and check that it's the correct one. Maybe something goes wrong at upload: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application