# http://www.sakshum.org/sakshumwebgae/8CB611AC7A0B5B6BE2C4C99A8EA4DEFE.cache.html not found

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

on our gae for java app using gwt on loading the app and checking in firebug i see error http://www.sakshum.org/sakshumwebgae/8CB611AC7A0B5B6BE2C4C99A8EA4DEFE.cache.html as a result gwt modules seems to be not getting loaded.

I am assuming this file should be auto generated by gae. so why i m facing it and what can be done to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your asumption is wrong. That file is generated by the GWT compilation (at the same time the `sakshumwebgae/sakshumwebgae.nocache.js` is generated) and should be deployed within your app.

Comment: so does this mean we should source control it as well? and if that is the case then why it gets missed when deploying the app via eclipse to app engine? shouldnt it automatically get included?

Comment: It's a compilation artifact, just like a `.class` file, so don't source-control it. It should be deployed automatically when using Eclipse (and BTW I just checked: your site is currently OK for me in both Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: well yeah as of now its fine but many a time i see that issue. and today the question came up because we are facing a strange issue as mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103783/issues-in-version-uploaded-on-google-app-engine .See if you can advise us on tht as well please.